# Minimize spectral radius with orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a real square and invertible matrix. I would like to find

$$
s(A) = \min_U \rho(U A),
$$
Where $U$ is orthogoal, i.e. $U U^T = I$ and $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius, i.e. the largest eigenvalue of $A$ in absolute values.

I am interested in a numerical solution to determine $s(A)$.

Comment: Isn't the answer just "singular value decomposition"? In other words, $U$ is the left matrix in SVD.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For an $n\times n$ matrix, the answer is
$$|\det A|^{\frac1n}.$$
Explanation: on the one hand, $\rho(UA)\ge|\det (UA)|^{\frac1n}=|\det A|^{\frac1n}$. On the other hand, singular value decomposition gives $A=PDQ$ where $P,Q$ are orthogonal and $D>0$ is diagonal. Then
$\rho(UA)=\rho(QUPD)$ and
$$\min_U\rho(UA)=\min_V\rho(VD)$$
where $V$ runs over the orthogonal group. Take for $V$ the permutation matrix associated with the cycle $(12\ldots n)$. We have
$$VD=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & s_1 \\ s_2 & \ddots & & & 0 \\ 0 & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots & 0 & s_n & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$
whose spectrum is made of the $n$-roots of $s_1\cdots s_n=\det D=|\det A|$.

Remark that the answer is valid for an arbitrary matrix, singular or not. It is valid for complex matrices too, provided one takes the minimum over unitary matrices $U$.

Comment: Thanks. That is a very helpful answer. I suppose there is a small typo: it should read $\rho(QUPD)$, right?

Comment: @SebastianSchlecht Of course ; I'll fix it. Besides, feel free to *accept* the answer :).